# Add cache on existing file cache PHP

Tags: php, caching

is possible add some data on a existing file cache? Should be useful in this scenario:

A user add a comment on his profile and the result will be put on the existing cache about his profile, so after i don't have to delete the previous cache for create a new.

is it possibile using php? I'm happy to hear some suggest about cache system that do what i'm looking for. For now I'm using a simple cache built for codeigniter. I know is not the best but i started with that for understand how the cache system work.

[Cache library](https://github.com/colettesnow/Simple-Cache-for-CodeIgniter)

Edit: I'm caching all the posts and comments on a unique file cache about a user. Example user A will have the file cache called cache_user_A, the user B will have cache_user_B ecc... so when the user A add a post or a comment i would like add on that file the datas submitted from the user

Comment: can you overwrite the cache with the new information?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Are you caching the comments for that specific user or do you need to update the user data cache for that user?

Comment: @Ibu this one is the my question.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I'm caching all the post and comments on a unique file cache about a user. Example user A will have the file cache called cache_user_A, the user B will have cache_user_B ecc... so when the user A add a post or a comment i would like add on that file the datas submitted from the user.

Comment: Just append to the file the new data ?...

Comment: @DavidBélanger Yes Exactly

Comment: @Gilbert Then do it ? Ueh... Open the file and write to it, not that hard...

Comment: So, you have even reason. But i tought was not possible. Cheerse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. The most straightforward one, aligned with how caches work, is to mark the user cache as dirty (or simply delete it).

When you delete the cache for the user, requesting it should trigger the cache to be newly generated. This depends on how your code is organized, but typically this is how your caches will work.

So, a user posts a comment. `cache_user_A` is deleted. User visits his profile. Profile creates `cache_user_A` and recalculates the number of posts, or shows the latest post or w/e.

---

What you *don't* want to do is generate the new value for `cache_user_A` when the user makes a post because this creates a strange kind of coupling. Suddenly many pieces of code are responsible for generating a cache. The one who needs the cache is also typically the one who can make it. So don't update your caches on update, update them on *reads*.

Comment: Exactly how i do right now... When the user A comment the cache will delete, and when some user go to visit his profile, the cache will store all the datas even with the new one. But my question was if i can append the data submitted on the previous cache, like that the profile will continue to load by cache.

Comment: You could do that, but I would strongly recommend you don't. Caching is one of the cross cutting concerns, keeping it simple allows you to understand what can and can't happen. Incremental updates on caches sounds waaaay overkill. You seriously have to think about how much impact this has on performance. I just don't think it's worth it, unless you're twitter, google or facebook.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the explanation. I'll continue with this way, deleting and refreshing the cache. Yes I know is very important cache the data for the performance but, i tought even that if i update the previous cache will be more effecient then delete and refreshing.